# C++ How to cache a variable of template type T in a class?

Tags: c++, templates, entity-component-system

Suppose that I have a `Foo` class like this, and I need many instances of it.

```cpp
class Foo {
  public:
    Pool* bars;  // a global list of bars, each may have a different type

    template<typename T>
    T& AddBar(int x) {
        return bars->emplace<T>(x);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& GetBar() {
        return bars->get<T>();  // a very slow function
    }
}
```

All the instances of `Foo` share the same pool of bars, which contains many bars of possibly different types. For example, `bars` may be a list of bars `{A bar1, B bar2, A bar3, C bar4}` where `ABC` are some class types, but each `Foo foo` instance can only have one bar of a specific type, e.g., a `foo` instance cannot have two bars of type `A`.

Given an instance `Foo foo`, I can get a specific type of bar using `foo.GetBar<A>()`, `foo.GetBar<B>()`, etc, but calling the `bars->get<T>()` function is slow and expensive. Therefore, I'm thinking of caching the result of `GetBar()` so that subsequent calls can return immediately without querying the pool again.

Now this is what I came up with: I created a static variable inside the member function to store the value of bar, it is only initialized and assigned value once.

```cpp
template<typename T>
T& GetBar() {
    static T bar {};
    if (bar == T {}) {
        bar = bars->get<T>();  // a very slow function
    }
    return bar;
}
```

The problem is that, using the `static` keyword, this variable is now shared across all instances of `Foo`. If I try to get a bar of type `A` from different instances, they would return the same result.

```cpp
Foo foo1;
Foo foo2;
foo1.AddBar<A>(1);
foo2.AddBar<A>(2);
foo1.GetBar<A>();  // returns a bar (type = A, value = 1)
foo2.GetBar<A>();  // returns the same bar with value 1, not 2
```

How can I cache every bar of type `T` inside the class and prevent it from being shared by other instances? I don't know how to store generic types as member variables, besides, storing each type `T` of bar can be a huge mess.

**Edit:** I know it'd be much easier to cache the result outside the class, on the caller's side. I'm just curious if there's an elegant way of caching inside the class.

**Edit2:** `bars` is a pointer to a registry pool, whose type is a complicated data structure, not a raw list or array. To clarify, I'm using the [EnTT](https://github.com/skypjack/entt) library to integrate entity-component-system into my application, but not sure how the pool is maintained internally in details.

**Edit3:** if you wonder what `ABC`s are, conceptually, these types are not known at compile time. but need to be determined at runtime. In fact, they are just many other class types I implemented, so I can also hardcode them into the `Foo` class, in which case I probably should use the factory pattern along with a scripting language for automatic code generation, but that would beat the purpose of using generics in the first place.

Comment: `Pool* bars;  // a global list of bars, each may have a different type` This doesn't parse. `bars` is a pointer. What does it mean for it to be a "list"? Does it point to an array of object of type `Pool`? In this case, they are all of the same type.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for your comment, I've edited the post.

Comment: You need to create a cache object that is able to store instances of different types. Just as you have `bar = bars->get<T>()`, you need to be able to say `bar = cache->get<T>()` and `cache->put<T>(bar)` and `if (cache->has<T>())`. None of this comes free in C++, you need to actually program it. One possible implementation employs `std::map<std::type_info, std::any>` inside.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thank you for your idea! I guess `std::map<Foo*, T>` might be an option, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Is the collection of types that `Foo` wants to cache defined at compile time? E.g. in you example only `A`, `B` and `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing a mockup, with the idea of n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m., for your "complicated registry pool" I wrote the actual could be implementation of `Foo`. I left in there `Foo` only to also give some suggestions. If you want so have more than one variable of one type you would have to change the value type of the map of course, like from `std::any` to `std::vector<std::any>`. Otherwise please clarify your question more.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <any>

struct Pool {
    template<typename T>
    void emplace(T x) {
        this->elements_.insert_or_assign(typeid(T).hash_code(), std::make_any<T>(x));
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& get() {
        return std::any_cast<T&>(elements_.at(typeid(T).hash_code()));
    }

private:
    std::map<std::size_t, std::any> elements_;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Pool& pool): bars_(pool) {}

    void AddBar(int x) {
        return bars_.emplace<int>(x);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& GetBar() {
        return bars_.get<T>();  // a very slow function
    }
private:
    Pool& bars_;
};

int main(){
    Pool pool;
    pool.emplace(4.3); pool.emplace(std::string("a value"));

    Foo foo1(pool);
    foo1.AddBar(3);

    std::cout << foo1.GetBar<int>() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: While I'm curious if caching can be done inside the `Foo` class, not inside the pool, I think this answer is clearer and more practical, I will mark it as accepted. I'm still new to C++ so can't tell if this is what I want, but a O(1) lookup into the map is definitely the best I can have.

Comment: Well a `std::map` lookup is in O(log(n)), but you could use an `std::unordered_map`   but more importantly, until you don't have at least, say 10000 entries in that container, it doesn't really matter. In fact, usually `std::vector` is the fastest data structure in most cases, but the map helps us to get correct code . Since if your code is incorrect, it doesn't matter how fast it is incorrect ;-)

Answer (score 1):

All ECS implementations abandon static type safety somewhere deep under their hood, although they can hide the ugly casts from the user or use the likes of `std::any` as in the other nice answer.

That said, here's an alternative way to approach it (simplified but it should give you the right idea) which avoids map lookups except once on calling the get function for a new type, T:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <any>

class Foo
{
public:
    template <class T>
    T& get()
    {
        // Fetch a unique index for T to use for our std::vector.
        const std::size_t n = type_index<T>();

        // Resize if it's a new type we're encountering.
        if (n >= bars.size())
            bars.resize(n+1);

        // Emplace if it's a former type of bar that's new for this instance
        // of Foo.
        if (!bars[n].has_value())
            bars[n].emplace<T>();

        // Returns the bar for that index cast to T&.
        return std::any_cast<T&>(bars[n]);
    }

private:
    // Stores all the elements.
    std::vector<std::any> bars;

    // Returns a unique type index for T.
    template <class T>
    static std::size_t type_index()
    {
        // Using static here avoids repeat lookups into the hash map.
        static const std::size_t n = lookup_type_index<T>();
        return n;
    }

    // Looks up a unique type index for T.
    template <class T>
    static std::size_t lookup_type_index()
    {
        // Warning: hash_code is not guaranteed to be unique for all
        // types in all compilers (two different types could return
        // the same hash code, e.g.). I recommend using something else but
        // that gets a bit involved (can expand and show you how if
        // needed). Also consider a lock here for thread safety.
        std::size_t key = typeid(T).hash_code();
        auto it = idxs.find(key);
        if (it != idxs.end())
            return it->second;
        idxs[key] = counter;
        return counter++;
    }
    static inline std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::size_t> idxs;
    static inline std::size_t counter = 0;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    Foo f, f2;
    f.get<int>() = 123;
    f.get<double>() = 1.23;
    f2.get<int>() = 456;
    f2.get<double>() = 4.56;
    cout << f.get<int>() << endl;     // --> 123
    cout << f.get<double>() << endl;  // --> 1.23
    cout << f2.get<int>() << endl;    // --> 456
    cout << f2.get<double>() << endl; // --> 4.56
}
```

<strike>I didn't bother to test it but it should give you the gist of the idea.</strike> *Update: I bothered to test it and updated it with a hasty program you can run after discovering some typos just double-checking what I wrote and realizing I ought to at least try to compile what I write.* To avoid constantly looking into a type map, we map types to an index into a vector. You can extend that with sub-indices and so forth as your original example suggests. The above illustrates the main idea.

Please note the warning in the code above about `std::type_info::hash_code` as it applies to both mine and the other answer. I can offer a safe and portable alternative and one that doesn't even require RTTI but that gets a bit involved. You can usually find a bunch of examples out there if you search for ways to portably map a type T to an integer at compile-time that you can use at runtime.